# Symfony's SwiftMailer configuration for SMTP 587 relaying port

Tags: symfony, ssl, configuration, smtp, swiftmailer

My hoster provides me with a SMTP server which uses relaying via SMTP AUTH on port 587 with STARTTLS. Therefore I configured my parameters.yml like the following:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host:  127.0.0.1
mailer_user: user
mailer_password: password
mailer_port: 587
mailer_encryption: tls
```

I am not sure if this is the right configuration. I want to send emails to someone else using this code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
           ->setSubject('A subject')
           ->setFrom($email)
           ->setTo($this->container->getParameter('contactemail'))
           ->setBody($content);

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Unfortunately this message will not be sent. I don't know why, because I don't know much about email configuration, SMTP and that stuff. Can someone help me and tell me if I configured something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your provider provides the smtp server ...

the smtp server is most likely not running on the same server/local ip as your symfony application.

```
mailer_host:  127.0.0. # <- change this to your provider's smtp server ip/hostname
```

Inspect your logfiles  in `app/logs/dev.log` for errors while sending the email.

Comment: My provider confirmed my configuration as correct. the smtp server is on localhost, so 127.0.0.1. Also there are no errors or any other output in the dev.log - why?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the username in yaml is the full email address instead of the part before @

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question. Perhaps you could expand on the answer?